# X11 "bleeds" the output of programs to the tty

Tags: x11, xorg, tty, startx

I use `bspwm` with a simple `.xinitrc` config file instead of a display manager, and there is only a simple `exec dbus-launch bspwm` command there.

Whenever I start a program via, for example, `dmenu_run` (which itself is started via `sxhkd` after sourcing `bspwmrc` file), the output from that program goes straight to the tty from which the X session was started. For instance if I run `echo` it will write the message to the tty, instead of just ignoring it (despite the fact that, from my understanding, there shouldn't be any file descriptors to which `echo` could write).

What confuses me most, is that many other programs that can too write to stdout (steam, firefox, mpv...), actually don't pollute the tty despite also being started via `dmenu_run`. **Why?**

And the worst thing yet, some programs like `w3m`, not only show their output but also stay interactive even after exiting the X11 session.

**Why and how** does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

X11 can be run like that, but it's not really meant to be run like that (or at least you got to accept that the X11 display server keeps the file descriptors and shares them with any subprocesses started by it).

If you don't like it, start X like most other people via a session manager, or redirect the X session's stdout/stderr to a file.